# Working with % in CSS: position:absolute and image size

Tags: css

I am trying to design a fluid layout with %, featuring books at 50% of the window height, with a quarter of the next book just visible, tempting one to scroll down.

Resizing the window should not change the layout, so the image size of the books, the margins, etc. should be given in %.

However, setting `.books {position: absolute}` for the containing `div`s, the size of the contained image shrinks to thumbnail size, although the images themselves are fairly large...

How does % as unit work? I figured 100% always is 100% of its containing element. Why would `position: absolute` change this?

A second question, even when working with %, changing only the window width changes the vertical layout. I had assumed that a the vertical and horizontal directions are independent.

Here are some code snippets.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="books">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="books">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="books">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 200%;
}
.books {
  height: 25%; /* =50% of window height */
}
```

EDIT: I found the culprit: I assigned a top margin in %, but all (top bottom left right) margin values are defined as % of the *width* of the parent... Strange.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css

```
.books img {width:100%; height:100%}
```

Comment: how do I keep the aspect ratio for the image, if I specify both width & height?

Comment: for example- if you have image size of 600 x 200 if your reduce it size 50% then its dimension willbe 300 x 100

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about `position: absolute`, The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element, therefore the % change of the containing div will affect the image size. Source: [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

From experience you'll end up running into a few issues with various browsers using % width and height. Fixing sizes and supplying multiple style sheets based on the detected device being used is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't change the % of the containing div, only its position. Why would that change the size of the contained image?

Comment: because the image size isn't defined. you'll need to supply a value for the image size in your css so that the image size does not change along with the container.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the heights of all parents, right up to html i.e.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 200%;
}
.books{
    height: 25%; /* =50% of window height */
}
.books img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you change to position: absolute, then the parent will be the next positional parent, which you can specify by making it position: relative (or position: absolute).
The above code will mean that resizing the window will change the layout. But you could set a specific size at some point in the chain, or do it with javascript?